rdiff-backup not working
Hello Ubuntu Askers and Answerers:
I'm having trouble getting rdiff-backup to work.
I am trying to backup my home directory /home/mini to a mounted drive at /mnt/1TB1_Internal
Here is an ls -lisa /mnt:
   2 4 drwxrwxr-x  3 mini mini 4096 Dec 13 10:10 1TB1_Internal

So, I'm pretty sure that mini owns and as priveleges to read and write at
/mnt/1TB1_Internal
Also, here is an ls -lisa at /mnt/1TB1_Internal:
9175041 4 drwxrwxr-x 2 mini mini 4096 Dec 13 10:20 mini
That shows that there is a directory /mnt/1TB1_Internal called mini that the owner "mini" have rights to read and write to.
When I issue the rdiff-backup command:
rdiff-backup /home/mini/ /mnt/1TB1_Internal/mini/
I get this message:
Fatal Error: File /home/mini does not look like an increment file.
Try restoring from an increment file (the filenames look like
"foobar.2001-09-01T04:49:04-07:00.diff").
mini@mini:/mnt/1TB1_Internal$
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!
Mr. Old
